# Sending email without providing emailid and password

Tags: asp.net

How to send email without providing my emailid and password in asp.net

Comment: Where exactly are you asked for your password? Please post your current code and explain the issues you are experiencing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, depending on how secure your mail server is you can just add to you web config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="192.168.0.1" port="25" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

That will just allow you to send e-mail through that server (change the IP to your mail server) , as any address you like (email is pretty insecure that way) without requiring credentials.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Comment: Yes, that provides the answer for sending an e-mail without requiring a username or password in asp.net

Comment: How? If the SMTP server requires a password, how does your configuration example help? You are making an assumption about the `deliveryMethod` as well.

Comment: He didn't say it requires password, he just wants to know how to send email without a username or password. That will in most basic setups allow for the user to send an email without needing a user/pass.

Comment: My point is that you are making an awful lot of assumptions on a single line of text and no context.

Comment: True, but based on the spelling of the question I'd guess on further details being little & it'd would be good to offer up a possible answer.